# If Allah created the universe then why Allah doesn't mention that (how) he created the universe instead of saying the duration of creating it?

Tags: allah

The question is simple: If Allah created the universe, why doesn't he mention how he created it instead of saying the duration of the creation.

The Qur'an states that "Allah created the heavens and the earth, and all that is between them, in six days" (7:54).